# C# Can't print ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I don't know why my code doesn't show the students, when I try to print all the ArrayList, only shows in the console:
**System.String[] 

System.String[]**

 for example I want it to show:

 **Name: Roxa 

Note1: 89 

Note2: 78**
Sorry for my bad english.

```
    static string[] student = new string [3];
    static ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int op = 0;

        do
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine("MENU");
            Console.WriteLine("1-) add student");
            Console.WriteLine("2-) all students");
            Console.Write("3-) SALIR");
            op = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();

            switch (op)
            {
                case 1: addStudent(); break;
                case 2: all(); break;
                case 3: Console.WriteLine("---FIN DEL PROGRAMA---"); break;
                case 4: Console.WriteLine("Tecla incorrecta");break;
            }
        } while (op != 3);

    }
```

**

```
    static void addStudent()
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Name:");
        student[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Nota1:");
        student[1] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Nota2:");
        student[2] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
        list.Add(student);
        Console.Clear();
    }
```

**

```
    static void all()
    {
        foreach (string[] a in list)
            Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: please if you really want to use `ArrayList` don't show it in public posts - this will cause a lot of unnecessary comments and in general will make reception of a post worse.

Comment: I have my pitchforks ready.